# Solve: the system contains a nonreal constant

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

The equations I wanted to solve is as follows

```
neweqns=Sin[a - b] == Sin[b] + Sin[b - d] && Sin[c] + Sin[c - d] == 0 && 
 Sin[a - d] + Sin[b - d] + Sin[c - d] == Sin[d] && 
 Sin[a] + Sin[b] + Sin[c] + Sin[d] == 
  0 && ((Sin[d] == 0 && 2 Sin[b] + Sin[c] == 0 && 
     2 Sin[a] + Sin[c] == 0) || (Sin[d] == 0 && Sin[c] == 0 && 
     Sin[a] + Sin[b] == 
      0) || ((Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[d] == 0 || 2 Sin[d] == Sqrt[3]) && 
     Sin[c] + Sin[d] == 
      0 && (Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[b] == 0 || 2 Sin[b] == Sqrt[3]) && 
     Sin[a] + Sin[b] == 
      0) || ((Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[d] == 0 || 2 Sin[d] == Sqrt[3]) && 
     Sin[c] == Sin[d] && Sin[b] + Sin[d] == 0 && 
     Sin[a] + Sin[d] == 
      0) || ((Sin[d] == -((3 I Sqrt[5])/2) || 
       Sin[d] == (3 I Sqrt[5])/2) && 3 Sin[c] + Sin[d] == 0 && 
     3 Sin[b] + Sin[d] == 0 && 3 Sin[a] + Sin[d] == 0))

Reduce[neweqns && 0 <= a < 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b < 2 \[Pi] && 
   0 <= c < 2 Pi && 0 <= d < 2 Pi, {a, b, c, d}, 
  Reals] // FullSimplify
```

However, I got the following error:
[image]

I have three questions about this:

1. How to avoid such error and obtain the solutions?
2. Should I add constraints on constants evolved in the solving process (add terms, eliminate terms, multiply terms, etc.) to be Reals? Will this active delete something which actually are solutions?
3. What does `<<1>>` mean in the error information?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Comment: Since the constraints restrict all of the variables to being real, it is not necessary to restrict the domain to `Reals`. Just remove the domain restriction. You could alternatively use `sol = Solve[neweqns && 0 <= a < 2 π && 0 <= b < 2 π && 0 <= c < 2 π &&0 <= d < 2 π, {a, b, c, d}, Method -> Reduce] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks! When I removed ```Reals```, it works. I am still confusing the reason.. Does domain mean the domain of all variables?

Comment: From the documentation for `Reduce`, "If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real." The presence of `I` causes a contradiction which is what the error message indicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since variables are real, Sin[d] can not bei imaginary, get rid off with Simplify. In a first step solve for Sin of variables, then solve all separate solutions  directly for variables.

```
neweqns = 
Sin[a - b] == Sin[b] + Sin[b - d] && Sin[c] + Sin[c - d] == 0 && 
Sin[a - d] + Sin[b - d] + Sin[c - d] == Sin[d] && 
Sin[a] + Sin[b] + Sin[c] + Sin[d] == 
0 && ((Sin[d] == 0 && 2 Sin[b] + Sin[c] == 0 && 
   2 Sin[a] + Sin[c] == 0) || (Sin[d] == 0 && Sin[c] == 0 && 
   Sin[a] + Sin[b] == 
    0) || ((Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[d] == 0 || 2 Sin[d] == Sqrt[3]) && 
   Sin[c] + Sin[d] == 
    0 && (Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[b] == 0 || 2 Sin[b] == Sqrt[3]) && 
   Sin[a] + Sin[b] == 
    0) || ((Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[d] == 0 || 2 Sin[d] == Sqrt[3]) && 
   Sin[c] == Sin[d] && Sin[b] + Sin[d] == 0 && 
   Sin[a] + Sin[d] == 
    0) || ((Sin[d] == -((3 I Sqrt[5])/2) || 
     Sin[d] == (3 I Sqrt[5])/2) && 3 Sin[c] + Sin[d] == 0 && 
   3 Sin[b] + Sin[d] == 0 && 3 Sin[a] + Sin[d] == 0));

ns = Simplify[neweqns, 
0 <= a < 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b < 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= c < 2 Pi && 
0 <= d < 2 Pi];

redsin = Reduce[ns, {Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c], Sin[d]}, Reals];

redsin // Length     (*   8   *)

redsin2 = 
Reduce[# && 0 <= a < 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b < 2 \[Pi] && 0 <=   c < 2 Pi &&
   0 <= d < 2 Pi, {a, b, c, d}, Reals] & /@ redsin;
```

.

```
TraditionalForm[
redsin2 //. 
Or -> Composition[(Column[#, Right, 
   Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

```
solsin2 = Solve[#, {a, b, c, d}, Reals] & /@ redsin2;

(neweqns /. # &) /@ solsin2 // FullSimplify

(*   True   *)
```